# Ubuntu 11.10 freezes from time to time, don't know why

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

I installed Ubuntu as a second Operating System on my (Dell) laptop 2 days ago.  Since then Ubuntu has frozen 4 seperate times.  I have no idea why.

The applicaitons that I have used during these freezes are:

- Chrome
- Ubuntu Software Center
- Terminal

I was wondering if it has anything to do with how I installed the Operating System. For reference, here is how I installed Ubuntu:

1. Partitioned the hard drive
2. Set GRUB to boot from the newly created partition
3. Installed Ubuntu
4. Set the installed the new partition to use Ext3

Everything seemed to work fine from this point on, up until Ubuntu started to freeze.

On an unrelated note: How can I move the Utility Dash thingy, where you can click on Home Folder, Dash home, etc.?  I want to move that to either the bottom or the top of the screen.

Please help! I am a novice Ubuntu user.

Comment: It might be graphic issue, I had exactly the same problem. Maybe your question gets better answers asking on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions).

Comment: This might help, [Can I move the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: @Gigili: That's exactly what i wanted, but i don't know how to install the plugins. I don't really understand how to get that special compiz.

Comment: Use [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-ubuntu-unity-bottom-launcher.html) for step-by-step guide.

Comment: @Gigili: I have followed everything and it went well until Step 3, i opened up compizsetting manager and disable ubuntu unity plugin then everything went blank except the terminal and compiz, then i accidently close compiz and didn't know how to get it back, so i did the final step down the bottom "Revert the change"  then after i read over a couple times, i found my way back to get ubuntu unity plugin then i did all over again from step 1 and then when i got up the last bit of step 2, it says

Comment: "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unityshell-rotated
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> doesn't work, there is a chance that your computer is overheating.

Comment: ctrl alt backspace is diabled in recent versions of ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a Linux system is broken, you can try the "Magic SysRQ". If this doesn't work, you have a kernel panic, and something much worse is wrong:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRQ</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Not all at once. Alt+SysRQ+R, then Alt+SysRQ...)

Comment: One should solve the main problem instead of these shortcuts. And it's not "Alt+SysRQ+R, then Alt+SysRQ", it's hitting REISUB when holding Alt+SysRQ+R. -1.

Comment: That's what I ment. I couldn't find a good way to describe it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers. Now how could i change the Utility Dash thingy from the left to the bottom? It's annoying when i move the mouse over to the far left and the dash pops up. how please!

Comment: I don't know. I never switched to Unity because I didn't like it. I use Gnome 2.

Comment: @James1: You can use "Alt+SysRq+S+K" instead, but none of these will fix the issue but just a way to postpone it.

Comment: Really? What do those do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you also experiencing bad/laggy graphics? You might need to find a driver for your laptop's graphics card. Do this by going System prefs -> Additional Drivers, and download/install the applicable graphics driver.

I realize the OP has probably fixed it or moved on with his life, just putting this suggestion here for posterity.